# Working with java.util.List from JRuby

Tags: java, arraylist, jruby

I am trying to call a Java method from JRuby and one of the arguments to the Java method needs to be an instance of `java.util.List`.  I cannot get this to work from JRuby.  When I try to create an instance of a List object in JRuby, it doesn't have the `[]=`  method for assignment elements to the List.

I think that I might need to write my own Java class with a method to convert an `ArrayList` to a `List`, but I am not Java developer and I don't know how to create this class.

---

Edits:  I am trying to automate the creation of a PDF with form elements using older open source Java software called 'PDF Forms Designer', which you can download here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfformsdesigne/files/pdfformsdesigne/0.8b05/forms_src.zip/download

I am trying to call the `write` method defined in the `org.pdf.forms.writer.Writer` class.  I am basically duplicating the code in the `publishPDF` method defined in the `org.pdf.forms.gui.commands.Commands` class.

I have the `widgets` argument setup as an instance of `ArrayList`, which is easy to work with in JRuby.  I just need to get it converted to a `List` so I can call the method to save out the PDF document.

Here is a bit of JRuby code that isn't working:

```
widgets = ArrayList.new()
widgets.add(documentProperties.getPage(1).getWidgets)
widgets.add(documentProperties.getPage(2).getWidgets)
writer.write(file, widgets.to_java(java.util.List), documentProperties.getDocumentProperties()) # throws an error
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.ArrayList` is of the type `java.util.List`. So I am not sure why you say you need to write a new class to convert `ArrayList` to `List`. Please paste your code and error to explain the issue.

Comment: When I try to pass the `ArrayList` variable to the Java method that expects a `List` variable, I get this error: `TypeError: failed to coerce java.util.ArrayList to [Ljava.util.List;`.  I will edit my post to add some code samples.

Comment: The problem you seem to be having is with the conversion of ArrayList to an array of List. An array of List is a different object from an array of ArrayList and cannot be type casted. your widgets.to_Java(java.util.List) will only give you an object of List and not List[].  Change your code to return List[] and it should work.